# Blank pages with Zen Cart v1.3.8 and PHP 5.3

Tags: php, zen-cart

I am trying to run a live Zen Cart store (version 1.3.8) on a my local machine which is PHP 5.3. I am aware of the incompatibilities between both versions and have dealt with it by applying the patch found here: http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=140960

I am able to login the admin side no problem, but when i navigate to the store - all I see are blank pages.

How can I fix this issue?

I'm hoping there is a fix somewhere. Trying not to revert to an older PHP installation.

Answer (score 3):

What about upgrading to ZenCart 1.3.9?

Comment: This is truly the correct fix.  1.3.8 has MANY serious security issues which have been fixed in 1.3.9.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for this issue:
http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=140960